# Can not take a full page screenshot in Applitools C#

Tags: c#, selenium, screenshot, applitools

I'm trying to take a full screen screenshot of my page by using this code:

```
public void OpenEyesForVisualTesting(string testName) {
 this.seleniumDriver.Driver = this.eyes.Open(this.seleniumDriver.Driver, "Zinc", testName);

}

public void CheckScreenForVisualTesting() {
 this.eyes.Check("Zinc", Applitools.Selenium.Target.Window().Fully());
}

public void CloseEyes() {
 this.eyes.close();
}
```

but instead I just get a half a page of the screenshot, I tried to contact `Applitools` but they just told me to replace `eyes.checkwindow()` to `eyes.Check("tag", Target.Window().Fully());` which still didn't work.

If anyone can help me that would be great.

Comment: If you are paying for Applitools, you are paying for support. Tell them it didn't work and they will help you figure out a solution.

Comment: I got no respond from them that's why I put the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for Applitools and sorry for your troubles. Maybe you did not see our replies or they went to your spam folder. You need to set ForceFullPageScreenshot = true and StitchMode = StitchModes.CSS in order to capture a full page screenshot.

The below code example is everything you'd need to do in order to capture a full page image. Also, please make sure your .Net Eyes.Sdk version is >= 2.6.0 and Eyes.Selenium >= 2.5.0.

If you have any further questions or still encountering issues with this please feel free to email me directly. Thanks.

```
var eyes = new Eyes();
eyes.ApiKey = "your-api-key";
eyes.ForceFullPageScreenshot = true;
eyes.StitchMode = StitchModes.CSS;

eyes.Open(driver, "Zinc", testName, new Size(800, 600)); //last parameter is your viewport size IF testing on a browser. Do not set if testing on a mobile devices.
eyes.CheckWindow("Zinc");
//or new Fluet API method
eyes.Check("Zinc", Applitools.Selenium.Target.Window().Fully();
eyes.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extent Reporting library, in that you can take screen shot as well as an interactive report on pass and fail cases. 
here is the link how it works: 
http://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/generate-extent-reports/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take complete page Screenshot/ Particular element with Applitools. You can use lines of code:-

**Full Screenshot**

```
eyes.setHideScrollbars(false);
eyes.setStitchMode(StitchMode.CSS);
eyes.setForceFullPageScreenshot(true);
eyes.checkWindow();
```

**Take screenshot for particular element**

```
WebElement Button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='login-btn']"));
eyes.setHideScrollbars(false);
eyes.setStitchMode(StitchMode.CSS);     
eyes.open(driver, projectName, testName);
eyes.setMatchLevel(MatchLevel.EXACT);       
eyes.checkElement(Button );
```

Answer (score 0):

(I am from Applitools.)

When setting `forcefullpagescreenshoot` to true, applitools will try to scroll the `HTML` element in the page, if the `HTML` is not the scrollable element then you will need to set it yourself:

```
eyes.Check(Target.Window().ScrollRootElement(selector))
```

In Firefox, you can see a scroll tag near elements that are scrollable.